# Ubuntu virtual display ratio

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, xorg

I've been trying - without any success - to create a "virtual" display device configured for 16:9 ratio resolution..

I'm already past setting a kernel option (forgot what it was) for xorg to even start up without a physical display device connected to the display port.

Below is my xorg.conf. What i would basically like to achieve is a 16:9 resolution such as 1440x900 instead of all the 4:3 resolutions this configuration apparently provides ( despite the modes and metamodes defined below, i only get to choose 4:3 resolutions like 1024x768 )

Thanks much!
Andras

ps: again, i have no physical display device.

```
pigeon@pigeon-desktop:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
Identifier "VNC Device"
Driver "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "VNC Screen"
Device "VNC Device"
Monitor "VNC Monitor"
SubSection "Display"
Modes "1440x900 1440x900@61"
Option "MetaModes" "1440x900,1440x900; 1280x1024,1280x1024; 1024x768,1024x768" 
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Modeline "1440x900@61" 111.17 1440 1472 1888 1920 900 918 927 946
Identifier "VNC Monitor"
Option "nodpms"
Option "noddc"
Option "ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck;NoEdidMaxPClkCheck"
HorizSync 30-85
VertRefresh 48-120
DisplaySize 400 225
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to run a headless server machine. If so, `Driver "vesa"` seems like a poor choice of drivers as I don't even know that 1440x900 is a valid mode.

You might want to look into a stright VNC server (like [tightvncserver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/tightvncserver)) or at least post the complaints from your `Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
this is my video device

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

i tried loading the "intel" driver, however with the above configuration it is trying to EDID the non-existant monitor and fails to start

log in next message

Comment: (II) intel(0): Output VGA using monitor section VNC Monitor
(II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA
(II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
(WW) intel(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
(II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
(WW) intel(0): Unable to find initial modes
(EE) intel(0): No valid modes.
(II) UnloadModule: "intel"
(II) UnloadModule: "vgahw"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Comment: Tip: blocks like that those last two comments are best edited into your original question, usually headed with **update** or **added**. I've got nothing much to offer beyond that you should be looking for the terms "virtual frame buffer" and "headless server" and "unbuntu or debian". It is hard for a driver to attach to hardware that doesn't exist.